# Free tool to create objects based on SQL tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am creating an web app from scratch and was wondering if there is a free tool that would allow me to convert my tables into objects, these objects would have things like create, update and delete methods and allow me to customize or create additional methods, classes if i want. I was looking at **netTiers** http://www.nettiers.com/ , but the problem with that one is that I would need **CodeSmith** http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator which I do not have the kind of money to spend at this moment. Is there any other tool I could use and that is free?.

All the other applications i have created, I had to create all the layers myself, but if there is something free that I can use to help me save time and that you can advise me I would be very thankful for such advise.

Thank you

Comment: What about Entity Framework?

Comment: I have never used it, can you add a link to a tutorial that you may recommend if its not too much to ask?

Comment: [Mindscape's ORM Lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed) - free for under 8 tables but works with almost any dB.

Comment: I wanted to point out that I work for CodeSmith Tools and we are always willing to work with customers on pricing. Just drop sales an email (http://www.codesmithtools.com/contactus). Also an old saying: A tool that can save you tons of time is well worth the price in gold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know for a long time I also thought about using tools like this, until I came across the entity framework, it's simple!

- create a connection to sql server
- find the table you want to model
- create a model file and open it (right click solution explorer, add, new item, select data, click  ado.net entity data model)

Then you'll run through a wizard to select the tables that you want to generate classes from.

Should be easy after that!

Comment: great!, the only part i am lost is "create a model file and open it". But i will see what I can find. Thank you very much

Comment: @user710502 model files(.edmx) that contains the objects and data mappings that you are going to query against and also the .

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 choices to consider, `Entity framework` and `LINQ to SQL`. LINQ is convenient way to query objects that are created out of relations. There is [OR designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that servers similar purpose to to convert tables to objects . Also,if you are going to deal with a lot of tables, you may want to use [`SQLMetal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) that gives you a `LINQ` wrapper for the underlying relational table. `SQlMetal` automatically creates methods for add,update and delete. You can customize the generated code and also hookup to events that it provides.

Comment: Linq to Sql has been in maintenance mode for a (long) while now. There is no active development for it nor bug fixing. EF5 was released with the VS 2012 a few months ago with new features (enum, spatial, support for TVFs, performance improvements etc.) and EF6 (Alpha released a few weeks ago with support for async and a few more features around migrations) is now open source - http://entityframework.codeplex.com/.